# Highchart long y-axis title may overlap with title when chart.styledMode set to true

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The y-axis title used to be split when it is too long. After styledMode is enabled, it seems not to work anymore. How do I work around this?
Please see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/capy0812/913gw5jt/1/) for the problem. Below is the javascript code.

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
    styledMode: true,
},
title: {
    text: "test",
  align: "left",
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},
    yAxis: {
    title: {
    text: 'Test maximum yAxis asdklfjas;lfks;alkfj;laskjf;alksjf;lkaljsf;jas;f',
  }
},
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you would like to have a styledMode on to customize some other properties, but yAxis.title should be rendered as it is by default.

In this case, you can disable styledMode only for axis.title by doing a wrap and title could by styled in chart config.

```
var H = Highcharts;

H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, 'addTitle', function(proceed, display) {

   proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    var axis = this,
    options = axis.options,
    axisTitleOptions = options.title,
    styledMode = axis.chart.styledMode;

  if (styledMode &&
    !axisTitleOptions.style.width &&
    !axis.isRadial) {
    axis.axisTitle.css({
      width: axis.len
    });
  }
});
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nkapu2ym/)

[Documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts)

Comment: Thanks. will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Because:

> When the **chart.styledMode** option is `true`, no presentational
>   attributes (like `fill`, `stroke`, font styles etc.) are applied to
>   the chart SVG. Instead, the design is applied purely by CSS.
>
> Highcharts comes with a default CSS file, [css/highcharts.css](https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css),
>   which is built from [SCSS](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/css/highcharts.scss).
>
> To customize your styles, you can [create your own themes with
>   SCSS](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/custom-themes-in-styled-mode), or just add your own individual CSS rules. See our [CodePen
>   boilerplate](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eQyawK) to experiment with the default SCSS.

This is just another way to style your chart. You need to choose how do you want to style your chart.

If you disable `styledMode`, then you can set style options right in config:

```
...
yAxis: {
    title: {
        enabled: true,
        text: 'very long title text here that will get cut off at the top when height becomes less than the length of the title',
        style: {
            font: 'bold 10pt Arial',
            color: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
            wordWrap:'break-word',
            width : "200px"
        }
    },
},
...
```